# CiviVolunteer (2.1.2) doesn't show the opportunities in the frontend on Wordpress (4.6) with CiviCRM (4.7.10)

Tags: wordpress, civivolunteer, 4.7.10

I was looking today and yesterday into installing CiviVolunteer on our CiviCRM installation (civicrm 4.7.10 on Wordpress 4.7) and when I try to navigate to the volunteer opportunities page from an event info page I only get a blank page with the header set to CiviVolunteer but no form loading.

There are no Javascript errors and all Wordpress roles have AjAX API as well as Register as Volunteer permissions.

You can see for yourself on a test instance at: https://piraten.lu/crm/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Finfo&reset=1&id=2

What could be the issue?

Comment: I am seeing this same issue. I have set up a volunteer project and when I went to post it (Here is the link I am using http://www.hopefreelutheran.org/civicrm/vol/3/volunteer/opportunities) I get nothing. I am using wordpress as well. I also have the ajax permission set on the anonymous users. Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick for me: 
/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/vol/#/volunteer/opportunities

instead of:
/civicrm/vol/#/volunteer/opportunities

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Angular Profiles extension installed and enabled? It's a prerequisite for CiviVolunteer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks ok to me pal (FireFox).
(I'm scheduled to volunteer shortly).

[image]