# What is CiviVolunteer URL when using Wordpress?

Tags: civivolunteer

We are using Civi 4.7.22 on Wordpress 4.8.22

I understand the URL to the Volunteer Opportunities in Drupal is something like this :
https://example.org/civicrm/vol/#/volunteer/opportunities
or
https://example.org/civicrm/vol/#/volunteer/opportunities?project=3

But what is the URL if you are using WordPress? Where do I find it?

Thank you.

Comment: See [https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/14542/civivolunteer-2-1-2-doesnt-show-the-opportunities-in-the-frontend-on-wordpres?rq=1](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/14542/civivolunteer-2-1-2-doesnt-show-the-opportunities-in-the-frontend-on-wordpres?rq=1)